# MySQL respectively select WHERE a IN (..) AND b IN (..)

Tags: mysql

I am not sure how to properly explain what I am trying to do, so I hope the title isn't too far off. But I want to select everything `IN` a range, where another value exists `IN` another range, **respectively**.

This is pseudo-code:

```
SELECT *
FROM table t
WHERE t.a IN (1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9)
AND t.b IN (a,c,b,c,d,e,f,g,h)
```

However, I only want to select [1,a], [2,b], [3,c] and so on. Not [3,h]. Is there a way to do this?
Maybe this better illustrates what I am trying to do:

```
WHERE [t.a, t.b] IN ([1,a], [2,b], [3,c], [4,d], [5,e], [6,f], [7,g], ...)
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Mysql **does support** such a syntax:

```
WHERE (t.a, t.b) IN ((1, 'a'), (2, 'b'), ...)
```

UPD:

For some funny reason I cannot find it in the documentation :-S

There are some reputable resources referring to it though: http://www.mysqlperformanceblog.com/2008/04/04/multi-column-in-clause-unexpected-mysql-issue/

Comment: Awesome, I was so close, I used the wrong brackets! And the MySQL documentation is a horrid hell of text from which there is no escape. I couldn't find it either.

Answer (score 2):

You can use `IN` for multiple columns.

Your example would work like this:

```
select * 
from t 
where (a,b) in ((1,'a'), (2,'b'), (3,'c'), (4,'d'), (5,'e'), (6,'f'), (7,'g'));
```

Answer (score 1):

`... AND FIND_IN_SET(t.a,'1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9') = FIND_IN_SET(t.b,'a,b,c,d,e,f,g,h')` would be a quick (but very dirty) way to do it, provided there are no `,`'s in the arguments themselves.

Comment: "would be a quick" --- quick from what perspective? It would require a table scan

Comment: Quick as in quickly implementable, but indeed, other options _are_ better. This should never be anything more then a _temporary_ hack, writing queries is a one time job, running them happens constantly.